# Get current index from an item in a QAbstractItemModel

Tags: qt, model

I have a Model/Item based design, similar to the one explained at http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/14121

What I really need is a method like RosterElement::currentIndex() which returns a QModelIndex object.
But I have no idea how to get the index without checking all indicies internalPointer() values against **this** (there should be only one single match, haven't tried it yet).
Are there any better implementations?

Comment: If I call beginInsertRows() I must supply a QModelIndex. If my model detects changes on the underlying data source, it refreshes the data automatically (using beginInsertRows() etc.). At this point, I only know the RosterElement on which child elements needs to be added. If it is "bad design" to get the corresponding QModelIndex at this situation, what other options do I have to update the model?!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem seems to revolve around how to get the `QModelIndex` of a parent `RosterElement` item so that you can emit a `beginInsertRows()` signal.

Have a look at the following examples which show you how to quickly determine where in the hierarchy an element is:

[Simple Tree Model Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html)

[Editable Tree Model Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwidgets-itemviews-editabletreemodel-example.html)

Answer (score 6):

Here are all options described: [How can a QModelIndex be retrived from the model for an internal data item?](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_project_org_faq#How_can_a_QModelIndex_be_retrived_from_the_model_for_an_internal_data_item.3F)